# Turn Wi-Fi offline via command line

Tags: windows, cmd

In windows 10, I want to create batch file with some sequence of commands. One of them is "turn OFF/ON WI-FI" (**not** enable/disable to module, the module must be **enable** all the time). That command is equal to turn off the Wi-Fi via GUI.
I found this [offline for netsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64OCB.png)

but not really understand which mode goes offline. It's sure not what I want' because my Wi-Fi is still working

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following steps that you need to follow
 1. Open command prompt (with Administrator Permission).
 2. Check your wifi hosted name.
 3. Run the following command to check if the hostedname wifi network is available
 `netsh wlan show hostednetworkname`
 4. Run the following command to turn off wifi
    `netsh wlan stop hostednetworkname`

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/696270/how-to-turn-on-wifi-via-cmd):

To do this using netsh:

Get the Interface Name:

`netsh interface show interface`

Enable the interface:

`netsh interface set interface "Interface Name" enabled`

To complete the solution to your problem, you could create a shortcut, and make it run on the startup of Windows. For example, if the name of your wireless adapter in netsh is Wi-Fi, the shortcut would look like this (one line):

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe interface set interface \"Wi-Fi\" enabled"`

The runas command ensures that the command is ran as administrator, which is required to bring the interface up or down. The /savecred switch will save the credentials, which might be asked the first time, but usually not after that.

Comment: It's exactly what I don't want. This command turn my modem to disable mode, and I need it stay in enable mode in both scenarios.